# When you go to the main screen during the game, the logo is displayed

Tags: unity-game-engine

In one scene, I made the main screen visible after the logo was displayed. This is "Scene 1"
If you press the play button on the main screen, the game screen appears. This is "Scene 2"
How do I go to the main screen from here?

If I simply move to "Scene 1", the main screen appears after the logo comes out.
What settings do I need?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get your question but, it seems that your problem is that after reloading the scene 1, you have the main logo and the start button overlaid.

To solve this you could create a static class that store the current game state with a bool and the class that control the menu have to take into consideration this bool.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have your logo display logic built into your "Scene 1". If you don't want the logo to display every time you navigate to the main screen, you could either 1) add logic into a script of your main scene to only display the logo once per game launch or 2) remove your game logo from the main scene and add it to the Splash Image setting in Player Settings (recommended).